# Null pointer exception quando tento realizar um @PUT

Tags: java

Estou testando o put pelo postman porém está dando null pointer exception quando tento realizar o @put

```
    @PUT
    @Path("/{idCliente}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response atualizarCliente(@PathParam("idCliente") int id, Cliente cliente) throws Exception {
        Cliente atualizarCliente = clienteDao.encontrarPorId(cliente.getIdCliente());
        System.out.println(cliente.toString());

        atualizarCliente.setIdCliente(cliente.getIdCliente());
        atualizarCliente.setNome(cliente.getNome());
        atualizarCliente.setCpf(cliente.getCpf());
        atualizarCliente.setEmail(cliente.getEmail());
        atualizarCliente.setDataDeNascimento(cliente.getDataDeNascimento());

        clienteDao.atualizar(atualizarCliente);

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

```
public boolean atualizar(Cliente cliente) throws Exception {
        boolean sucessoUpdate = false;

        String sql = " UPDATE CLIENTE SET NOME = ? , CPF = ? , EMAIL = ? , DATA_NASCIMENTO = ? WHERE IDCLIENTE = "
                + cliente.getIdCliente();

        Connection conexao = Banco.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = Banco.getPreparedStatement(conexao, sql);

        try {
            Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(cliente.getDataDeNascimento());

            prepStmt.setString(1, cliente.getNome());
            prepStmt.setString(2, cliente.getCpf());
            prepStmt.setString(3, cliente.getEmail());
            prepStmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(data.getTime()));

            int codigoRetorno = prepStmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            if (codigoRetorno == 1) {
                sucessoUpdate = true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao atualizar Cliente. Causa: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            Banco.closePreparedStatement(prepStmt);
            Banco.closeConnection(conexao);
        }

        return sucessoUpdate;
    }

    public Cliente encontrarPorId(int id) {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

        Connection conn = Banco.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = Banco.getStatement(conn);
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE IDCLIENTE = " + id;
        try {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if (rs.next()) {
                cliente.setIdCliente(rs.getInt(1));
                cliente.setNome(rs.getString(2));
                cliente.setCpf(rs.getString(3));
                cliente.setEmail(rs.getString(4));
                cliente.setDataDeNascimento(rs.getString(5));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Erro ao executar a Query que verifica existência de Cliente por ID. Erro:" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            Banco.closeResultSet(rs);
            Banco.closeStatement(stmt);
            Banco.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return cliente;
    }
```

e estou colocando no postman a url http://localhost:8080/api/clientes/1 com o body em json

```
  {
    "IDCLIENTE": 1,
    "NOME": "Alice",
    "CPF": "11111111112",
    "EMAIL": "alice@gmail.com",
    "DATADENASCIMENTO": "1998-03-31"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o NullPointer está na linha System.out.println(cliente.toString()); que não está chegando o objeto cliente nesse método.

Verifica se os dados que está passando no postman está igual aos que o método recebe no caso o Cliente.

no paramerto Cliente cliente coloca o @RequestBody antes, assim @RequestBody Cliente cliente.

Comment: O null pointer exception parou depois que tirei o sysout mas mesmo com o request body não está chegando o objeto preenchido :( No postman coloquei o nome das variaveis iguais do java e está retornando um 200 ok, porém não está atualizando

Comment: Agora você precisa Debugar.
Antes do retorno coloque um break point no começo do método e veja se o Cliente vem preenchido.
Se sim o problema está nos seus métodos para baixo, então adiciona mais break point até achar o motivo.
Desta forma você vai ver como está se comportando seus dados enviados.

Comment: É o id não estava vindo preenchido dentro do cliente, arrumei e foi!! mt obrigada!!!

Comment: Disponha, uma boa prática é sempre debugar para ver o comportamento do sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta colocar isso:

Coloca `@RequestParam("idCliente") int id` e `@RequestBody Cliente cliente`

```
public Response atualizarCliente(@RequestParam("idCliente") int id, @RequestBody Cliente cliente) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Add o RequestBody antes do cliente porém aparece erro quando tento colocar o RequestParam, não está dando a opção de importar ele

Comment: @LaisSant'ana deixa `@PathParam("idCliente")` para ver se resolve :)

Comment: Parou de dar o null pointer, porém não está alterando o cliente. No postman está retornando 200 mas quando faço o get nesse id nada foi modificado